how to change code style format on flutter
I am developing with Flutter using Android Studio. When I try to format the code using the Cmd + Opt + L keys, it ends up like #1 below.
Is there a good way to make it look like #2?
//#1
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        const Text("signup page"),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint("");
            },
            child: const Text(""))
      ],
    )));
  }

//#2

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text("signup page"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("");
              },
              child: const Text("")
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }

I tried using analysis_options.yaml and .editorconfig, but I couldn't find an option to configure it the way I want.
Is there anything I might have missed?

control+shift+f

Try cmd+alt+L key to format code.

To formate the code you have to add commas , commas make the code take the line for itself,
like this:
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Text("signup page"),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                debugPrint("");
              },
              child: const Text(""),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Hope that helps.

this is the first kind with dart autoformatting
Text ('abcd',style:textstyle:fontSize: 20),  

but the same code can be arranged as
Text ('abcd',
      style:textstyle:fontSize: 20,
),  

how can this be done?
simply add a comma at the end of line.
